# Multiple Python scripts running with their own MSAccess database - conflicts

Tags: python, ms-access

I have a script that creates an access db and populates it with data and queries and performs a compact and repair.

The script gets called via command line via a .bat file, and i need multiple of these scripts running concurrently.

I'm getting an error where basically the it thinks the current database is the database from the other script that concurrently running.

i think i either need to update the code so that it creates a separate instance for each script (which i think it already is) or update it so that it doesn't need to use the OpenCurrentDatabase() method, but dont know what alternative i have? can't get answers via google

```
if bool(config.query_create_dict):
    logging.info("Creating and Executing Queries")
    try:
        oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")

        # CREATE QUERIES
        oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(config.access_db_filepath)
        currentdb = oApp.CurrentDb()
        for order_id, query_dict in config.query_create_dict.items():
            name = query_dict["Name"]
            sql = query_dict["SQL"]

            # replace @valuation_date, with month end
            sql = sql.replace("@valuation_date", "{}".format(config.valuation_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))

            logging.info("Creating query: {}".format(name))
            currentdb.CreateQueryDef(name, sql)

        # EXECUTE QUERIES
        for order_id, name in config.query_execute_dict.items():
            logging.info("Running query: {}".format(name))
            currentdb.Execute(name)
        currentdb = None
        oApp.DoCmd.CloseDatabase

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        raise e

    finally:
        currentdb = None
        oApp.Quit
        oApp = None
```

Comment: If all you're doing is DAO stuff, you shouldn't use `Access.Application` at all. Use `DAO.DbEngine` and `OpenDatabase`. However, using an Access database in server applications or other applications that require it to be stateless is explicitly not supported

Comment: doing everything you can basically. creating new dbs, reading in csvs, adding and executing queries, compacting, running macros, and applying passwords. For both .mdb and .accdb file types.

Comment: a potential solution is to use DispatchEx instead of Dispatch.

https://python.developreference.com/article/22324717/Using+pywin32%2C+what+is+the+difference+between+Dispatch+and+DispatchEx%3F